# FIXED * React Native Expo - FlatList not Showing when using API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile, expo

Solution:

> ISSUE IS FIXED. This is what I did, instead of using "localhost" on my API endpoint link, I used my local IP Address. So it's "HTTP://192.168.0.0/client. Case closed

I just need some help. This is pretty weird.

[Check this image out to see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vi5J.png)

On my React Native Expo app, If I use declared constant array of values on the SendCollectors.tsx, the list appear on both mobile app but if I use my RestAPI custom hook, it does not appear on the mobile app but appear on the web.

There are no errors and my API endpoint is working well. I'm just at my wits end.

I tried clearing the cache, checking if JSON format corresponds with my type interfaces, no server sided errors, used console log to see the MAPPED response data (mapped data based from the API endpoint is returned by the browser)

SendCollectors.tsx

```js
export default function SendCollectors(){
    const [sendRequest, loading, error, client_user, reseller_user, collector_user] = RestAPI(); 

    useEffect(() => {
        sendRequest({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: "http://localhost:8080/client"
        })
    },[] )

    return(

        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.textHeader} >Assign Collectors</Text>
                <FlatList
                    data={client_user}
                    keyExtractor={(client: IClient) => client.client_id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item: client }) => (
                        <SendCollectorsList
                        client_id={client.client_id}
                        fullname={client.fullName}
                        />
                    )}
                />

            </View>       
        </SafeAreaView>

    );
}
```

RestAPI.tsx

```js
export interface IClient{
    client_id: number, 
    username: String, 
    password: String, 
    fullName: String, 
    address: String, 
    email: String, 
}


export const RestAPI = (): [(config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) => void, boolean, string,IClient | any, IReseller | any, ICollector | any] => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [client_user, setClientUser] = useState<IClient[]>([]); 
    const [reseller_user, setResellerUser] = useState<IReseller[]>(); 
    const [collector_user, setCollectorUser] = useState<ICollector[]>(); 

    function sendRequest(config: AxiosRequestConfig<any>) {
        setLoading(true);

        axios(config)
            .then((response) => {
                setError('');
                console.log(response);
                setClientUser(response.data); //YOU NEED TO ADD THIS TO PUT ALL RESPONSES TO THE USESTATE
                setResellerUser(response.data);
                setCollectorUser(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError(error.message);
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }

    



    return [sendRequest, loading, error, client_user, reseller_user, collector_user];

}
```

Comment: ISSUE IS FIXED. 

This is what I did, instead of using "localhost" on my API endpoint link, I used my local IP Address. So it's "HTTP://192.168.0.0/client. 

Case closed.